# Joining client to Server in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp

Having installed the trial of Server 2012 and a copy of Win 7 Pro in VirtualBox, I now need to join them together so the client can be in the domain of the server. I need to deactivate dhcp within VirtualBox to do this but don't understand what the help file is trying to tell me...
Many thanks for any suggestions,

Al

Comment: You don't need to deactivate DHCP.

Comment: I was told that was a requirement if I wanted to use Server 2012 as the DHCP server...

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to use a different DHCP server you'll need to deactivate the current one, but that has no impact on joining Windows 7 to a domain (barring any other network configuration issues).

Comment: Oh, right thanks. Yes I will want to use the Microsoft server for DHCP and DNS so I will need to deactivate the VirtualBox one, I just have no idea what the help files are trying to say to me in regard to this or the steps involved in adding this client to the Active Directory domain...

Comment: Please try to change the VB network settings from NAT to bridged. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget about DHCP for the moment. I don't have VirtualBox handy and have no memory of its DHCP settings.

It seems like the reason you're getting held up on DHCP is because you need to change the DNS settings to point to your Domain Controller. Yes, DHCP does hand out the DNS server addresses, but we can also override this.

On your Windows 7 machine, open up Network Connections. I find it's easiest to search for it in the Start Menu:

[image]

Right click on the connected network adapter and select Properties.

[image]

Select TCP/IPV4 and hit Properties.

[image]

Now select 'Use the following DNS server addresses' and punch in your Server's IP address. Leave the alternate blank (Since we only have one DNS server! Don't do this in a work environment.)

[image]

Now that our Windows 7 machine can contact the Domain Controller, we're ready to join to the domain. Open up System from the Control Panel and click Change Settings.

[image]

Punch another Change button (yay redundancy!).

[image]

Select Domain and type in the name of your domain.

[image]

It will prompt you for credentials. Punch in your Administrator creds and hit OK. Now reboot, and the PC is joined to the Domain.

Comment: I get as far as this last step and when I OK after entering the domain I an error box appear saying "An AD DC for the domain could not be contacted"

Comment: Ah, something is wrong with your network settings then. What are the IP addresses for both the server and the client? Are you sure they're both in the same network under Virtual Box?

Comment: No, the server is statically set to 10.1.10.2/24 whereas the client keeps getting set to 10.0.2.15 - presumably by the VirtualBox DHCP...

Comment: Ah, so that's what we need to fix... Make sure you've got them both on the same 'virtual network' or whatever VirtualBox calls it, then set a static IP for the DC at 10.0.2.100 or something.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, thanks for all your help - give me a minute...

Comment: Same error message, have set client preferred DNS to 10.0.2.10, server addresses to 10.0.2.10 with a default-gateway of 10.0.2.2 all with a /24 mask but still the client can't contact the server...

Comment: Hmm, my guess is that they're under different 'networks' in VirtualBox. Are they all in 'Host-Only' mode? This might help sort it out: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Will have a look at some YouTube tutorials, thanks again for your help, anything else you may think of....

Comment: Thanks, Tanner. Having had a brief look at what's on the link you sent me it looks as though this maybe what I've been looking for. Perhaps I can now get set up and start learning Server 2012....

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, the solution was to simply put both the Server 2012 machine and the Win 7 Pro client into "Internal" in Settings>Network. I still haven't got internet access on either machine but at least now I can get on with learning to administer the server and Active Directory. My host laptop has internet access.

Happy days!!! And it's my birthday, how cool is that!!!